# Adding multiple QTreeWidgetItems

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Im trying to build a QTreeWidget that has multiple QTreeWidgetItems, i tried to add some of them manually and it works. My question is how can i add the items using a for or a while loop.

here is a part of my code

```
Dwidget= new QDockWidget(this);
Dwidget->setAllowedAreas(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);

treeWidget= new QTreeWidget(Dwidget);

Titem= new QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget);
Titem1= new QTreeWidgetItem();
Titem2= new QTreeWidgetItem();
Titem3= new QTreeWidgetItem();

Titem->setText(0,"WriterIdenSystem");
Titem->setIcon(0,*(new QIcon("D:/Users/200656336/Documents/Writer Identification/data_repository_icon.jpg")));

Titem1->setText(0,"Database for Writer Identification");
Titem1->setIcon(0,*(new QIcon("D:/Users/200656336/Documents/Writer Identification/card_file.png")));
Titem2->setText(0,"0001");
Titem2->setIcon(0,*(new QIcon("D:/Users/200656336/Documents/Writer Identification/Folder Open.png")));

Titem3->setText(0,"0002");
Titem3->setIcon(0,*(new QIcon("D:/Users/200656336/Documents/Writer Identification/Folder Open.png")));

Titem->addChild(Titem1);
Titem1->addChild(Titem2);
Titem1->addChild(Titem3);
treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(Titem);

connect(treeWidget, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)), SLOT(on_actionRetrieve_Documents_triggered()));

Dwidget->setWidget(treeWidget);
addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea,Dwidget);
Dwidget->show();
```

any ideas?? :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, could could do something like this.

```
QTreeWidgetItem* items[ITEM_COUNT]; // Must be multiple of 3
QTreeWidget* treeWidget = new QTreeWidget;
if(!treeWidget){ /* operating system out of memory, handle the error */ }
for(int i=0;i<=(ITEM_COUNT-3);i+=3)
{
   items[i  ] = new QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget);
   if(!items[i]){ /* operating system out of memory, handle the error */ }
   items[i+1] = new QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget);
   items[i+2] = new QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget);
   /* set text here */
   items[i  ]->addChild(items[i]);
   items[i+1]->addChild(items[i+1);
   items[i+1]->addChild(items[i+2);
   treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(items[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Christian for you help :) if i'm right the code you provide me is to insert all the items in the tree. in my code i need the parent and the first item (Titem and Titem1) to be fixed and the remaining items, i want them to be inserted using a loop where their name is the same as the loop index. in my code i only added 0001 and 0002 and still many others.